# Search for a table then column and copy the data in the column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that starts with two data validation drop down lists, one for day and one for time. I want to create a macro that shows the corresponding data for the selected day/ time combo. Right now, on another sheet is a table for each day, with that day's hourly data in the columns of the table. Ideally, once both DV list cells are changed, the macro would find the correct day's table, find the right hour column, then select the data and paste it into a range on the sheet. What I have so far runs but doesn't actually do anything.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tbl As ListObject, sht As Worksheet, clm As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Data")

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
        If tbl.Name = Sheets("Heat Map").Range("B1").Value Then
                For i = 1 To NumCols
                    If Cells(2, i).Value = Sheets("Heat Map").Range("B2").Value Then
                        Sheets("Heat Map").Range("B4:B21").Value = tbl.Range(Cells(3, i), Cells(20, i)).Value
                    End If
                Next i
        End If
    Next tbl

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you add a breakpoint and step through the code?

Comment: @SJR - Fairly new to VBA so not sure what a breakpoint is, but when I run click debug an run to curser (at the end), it comes up with no errors, but it also doesn't do what I think it should

Comment: So have you Googled "VBA breakpoint debug" to learn what it is? Step debug code, watch each line execute, see if execution is as expected for the inputs.

Comment: Unless I am doing this wrong, I am getting a type mismatch at ```For Each tbl in worksheet("data")``` which doesn't make sense because I've used that exact syntax before no problem